# Supabase create sql function with count and group by

Tags: database, sql-function, supabase

I'm having trouble figuring out this sql-function for Supabase.

```sql
create or replace function get_dates(user_id_input uuid, friend_id_input uuid) 
returns setof available_dates
language sql 
as $$ 
SELECT date, COUNT(date) 
FROM available_dates
where user_id = (user_id_input)
or user_id = (friend_id_input)
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT(date) > 1;
$$;
```

All I get now is the error: Failed to run sql query: syntax error at or near " ".

I've tried some simpler ones and got them to work. The sql-query itself works outside of the function. It seems the trouble starts when I'm trying to use COUNT and GROUP BY. I've tried some with the placeholders as well (user_id_input uuid, friend_id_input uuid), so I don't think that's the problem.

My table looks like:

```
id|  date       |user_id

1 | 2022-08-08 | 8888888888

2 | 2022-08-08 | 4444444444

3 | 2022-08-04 | 8888888888

4 | 2022-08-06 | 4444444444
```

What I want from my query is the dates from the specific users where the dates are the same. When i run the pure sql-query I get:

```
date       | count

2022-08-08 |   2
```

Does anyone see whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, so sorry if my suggestion does not work.

You set the return type of the function as setof available_dates, which means the return type must match the table schema of available_dates, but in the actual data that you are returning, you don't have a date column, but instead have a int column. At least that could be one reason of not working. You can just return setof records instead to remove this error.

```sql
create or replace function get_dates(user_id_input uuid, friend_id_input uuid) 
returns setof records
language sql 
as $$ 
SELECT date, COUNT(date) 
FROM available_dates
where user_id = (user_id_input)
or user_id = (friend_id_input)
GROUP BY date
HAVING COUNT(date) > 1;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer! Turns out it was actually nothing wrong with the function, it just didn't work on my computer! On my friends computer it worked like a charm! I thought I removed this question, but seems i failed! Thanks!